# Is there any difference between " As I slept, it started to snow" and "As I was sleeping, it started to snow"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning, conjunctions

I couldn't have found any differences between them. Are there any ? or do both of them have the same meaning ?

Comment: The second sentence sounds a bit like causation: "Because I was sleeping, it started to snow." IMO it would be better to use 'while' instead of 'as' in both sentences. Compare with "as I fell / was falling asleep..." The 'as' seems more related to an event, not a duration of time.

Comment: Why would you think there is such a difference? Which are the rules you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, there is no difference in this case.**

"I slept" and "I was sleeping" can have different uses, but in this case, when the other action occurred at the same time, there is no difference.